# Deferring expansion in a Windows command line with nested commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a command line that's being invoked by a third party executable (Intune Management Extension). Unfortunately, this executable prefers to expand environment variables in my command line before executing them. Further, it doesn't load system environment variables before it does this expansion.

So, if I put something like this in the command line, it resolves to nothing:

```
cmd /s /c "echo profile is: %userprofile%"
profile is:
```

I've found I can work around the problem by using delayed expansion as follows:

```
cmd /s /v /c "echo profile is: !userprofile!"
```

However, this breaks down in my real scenario, which is the following:

```
cmd /s /v /c "cmd /s /v /c "cmd /s /v /c "echo hello" > !userprofile!\tst.log""
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

however, oddly, this works:

```
cmd /s /v /c "cmd /s /v /c "echo hello" > !userprofile!\tst.log"
```

Can someone explain to me why the additional level of nesting breaks this?

An alternative acceptable answer to this question: how can I take an arbitrary sequence of valid command lines, combine them into a single line command chain safely (using &&) and redirect the output of ALL of them to an output log file? Keep in mind, my limitation here is that this is third party software and has the ability to execute a **single** command line.

A real world example - I have 3 commands:

1. Installs some software: `powershell .\Install.ps1`
2. Records if the software was installed successfully: `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Foo\bar" /v "Installed" /d "%date:~4% %time%" /f /reg:64 > nul`
3. Outputs to a log file in the user profile directory: `>> %userprofile%\tst.log`

How can I combine this into a single command line?

Right now, I have

```
cmd /s /c "cmd /s /c "cmd /s /c "powershell .\Install.ps1" && reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Foo\bar" /v "Installed" /d "%date:~4% %time%" /f /reg:64 > nul" >> "%userprofile%\install.log" 2>&1"
```

This works, with the exception of the early expansion of %userprofile%...

Note - the executing third party software blows up if my outer command redirects the output (`>>`), hence the extra layer of wrapping...

Comment: for one `%` to "survive" one level of parsing, you need to escape it: `%%`. To "survive" two levels of parsing, double them again: `%%%%`

Comment: doesn't work if the calling program tries to expand environment variables before invoking the command

Comment: That's the point: `%%var%%` *isn't* expanded to the value of `%var%`, but "translated" into a literal `%var%`.

Answer (score 0):

The special characters in the command line is `%`, `&`, `>` and `!`. Some of these characters may need to be escaped to delay their use. If present in a string i.e. `">"`, then this can make them literal or if `cmd` removes the surrounding `""` from the command line, may just delay their special action once they are no longer part of a string.

Can escape `%` with by doubling or more if needed i.e. `%%`. `&`, `>` and `!` can be escaped with a caret `^` if needed. `%` and `!` can remain special in strings. View *ss64.com* about [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).

In the OP, you have tried delayed expansion using `cmd /v` and replacing `%` with `!`.

You have also tried nesting `cmd` commands with up to 3 instances.

Consider example 1:

```
cmd /c echo 1 && echo 2 > file.txt 2>&1
```

Expectation is:

- `cmd /c echo 1` will execute.
- `echo 2 > file.txt 2>&1`  will execute if already in a `cmd` process.

Consider example 2:

```
cmd /c (echo 1 ^&^& echo 2) > file.txt 2>&1
```

Expectation is:

- `cmd /c (echo 1 ^&^& echo 2) > file.txt 2>&1` will log line `1` (+ <kbd>Space</kbd>) and line `2` to `file.txt`.
  The `&&` is delayed by the preceding `^` before each character and the `echo` output is grouped by `()` so that file.txt gets all output.

The actual command to try:

```
cmd /v /c (powershell -file .\Install.ps1 ^&^& reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Foo\bar" /v "Installed" /d "!date:~4! !time!" /f /reg:64 ^> nul) >> "!userprofile!\install.log" 2>&1
```

I do not have or have I previously used *Intune Management Extension* to be certain of success. The use of `cmd /v` and use of `!` instead of `%` is based on your testing results etc.